# compile the examples of ffmpeg in C99 get wrong info

Tags: c, ffmpeg

I can run "make examples" using the ffmpeg build environment to get the .o files.
But I cannot compile using C99. The operating system I use is Ubuntu 14.04 and I configure ffmpeg following [Installation of FFmpeg-2.8.5 in linux](http://linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/multimedia/ffmpeg.html), installing it without error.

Here is the detail(demuxing_decoding demuxing_decoding.c is in the ffmpeg_souce_folder/doc/examples):

```
 c99 -o demuxing_decoding demuxing_decoding.c -lavdevice -lavformat -lavcodec -lavfilter 
-lavutil -lswresample -lswscale -lz -lbz2
```

```
demuxing_decoding.c: In function ‘main’:
demuxing_decoding.c:326:9: warning: ‘avcodec_alloc_frame’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/libavcodec/avcodec.h:3927) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
         frame = avcodec_alloc_frame();
         ^
demuxing_decoding.c:406:9: warning: ‘avcodec_free_frame’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/libavcodec/avcodec.h:3952) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
         avcodec_free_frame(&frame);
         ^
/tmp/ccgEq0Zc.o: In function `decode_packet':
demuxing_decoding.c:(.text+0x561): undefined reference to `av_frame_unref'
/tmp/ccgEq0Zc.o: In function `open_codec_context':
demuxing_decoding.c:(.text+0x5f4): undefined reference to `av_get_media_type_string'
demuxing_decoding.c:(.text+0x66c): undefined reference to `av_get_media_type_string'
demuxing_decoding.c:(.text+0x6df): undefined reference to `av_get_media_type_string'
/tmp/ccgEq0Zc.o: In function `main':
demuxing_decoding.c:(.text+0xcc1): undefined reference to `av_frame_alloc'
demuxing_decoding.c:(.text+0x1082): undefined reference to `av_frame_free'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I don't where is wrong...I've got stuck for two days...Needing your help. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally figure out my problem. Before I rebuilt ffmpeg I used `apt-get` to install ffmpeg. Only using `sudo apt-get remove ffmpeg` to remove it is not enough, run this command `sudo apt-get remove libavutil-dev libavutil-extra-51` additionally. After that, rebuild the ffmpeg. Everything is fine~